# Inconsistent offset() and top() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the position of the footer on my page, however, the values I get back from using offset and position().top are very inconsistent.

```
jQuery(function(){
     var test1= jQuery('#footer').offset();

     var test2 = jQuery('#footer').position().top;
     console.log(test1);
     console.log(test2);
})
```

I also made sure that I load them at the end so that the DOM is ready so I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: Inconsistent how? You know they aren't even close to being the same thing, one returns the position in the parent, the other in the document, so in most cases they'll return different values. If that's the "inconsistency", it's by design?

Comment: `.position()`: "Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, **relative to the offset parent**"; `.offset()`: "Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, **relative to the document**"

Comment: I'm just testing out both of them, but they seem to be returning the same values as each other. What I mean by inconsistency is that every time you refresh the page the value is different.

Comment: Then you probably have images or other resources that are still loading and change the offsets etc. Try using `$(window).on('load', function() {..`

Comment: @adeneo That seem to have done the trick. Thanks!